# Is it possible to generate a random number in the parameter of a function when the function is called?

Tags: java

I have written a Java program that calculates square root of a number, I am not using the in-built functions. The method used is **divide and average**. The method requires two inputs : "X" and a random number "n" where n < X.

Usually when generating a random number, I use :

```
Random generator = new Random();
double guess = (double)generator.nextInt((int)(X - 1));
```

What I want is that a function similar to the one given below :

```
static double sqrt(double X, generator.nextInt(int)X)
```

something like this must execute during function call. Is it possible? Kindly guide me through this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you want a random number everytime the function is called just make the generator an instance variable, and call generator.nextInt(int)X) inside your sqrt function

Comment: Why don't you just make a variable within your function that creates a random number, rather than passing in a random number?

Comment: Pass only the first parameter and calculate the random value inside the function?

Comment: Dimitris missed a "("
generator.nextInt((int)X)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could generate the random number in the function first line:

```
double sqrt(double X) {
double randX = (double)generator.nextInt((int)X); 
//rest of the code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write a wrapper for your function:

```
static double sqrt_(double x){
  return sqrt(X, generator.nextInt(int)X)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you are implementing the divide and average algorithm.  In that you guess once, and then perform divide and average multiple times, that could mean calling sqrt_ recursively.

```
class SomeClass {
  Random generator = new Random();

  private double sqrt_(double X, double guess) {
  ...
  }

  public double sqrt(double X) {
    return sqrt_(X, (X-1)*generator.nextDouble()));
  }
}
```